# Android java.lang.exceptionininitializererror System.loadLibrary

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to load prebuild native shared library from MainActivity of my project in following way:

```
static
{
System.loadLibrary("mylib.so"); // I have tried this way
//System.loadLibrary("libmylib.so"); // Also tried this way
//System.loadLibrary("mylib"); // Also tried this way
}
```

But all times it throws following exception:

Warning before exception:

```
07-12 11:08:36.019: W/dalvikvm(21552): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/libtest/src/MainActivity;
07-12 11:08:42.790: W/dalvikvm(21552): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/libtest/src/MainActivity;)
07-12 11:08:47.067: D/AndroidRuntime(21552): Shutting down VM
07-12 11:08:47.067: W/dalvikvm(21552): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
```

Then exception:

```
07-12 11:08:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 11:08:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21552): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-12 11:08:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21552):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-12 11:08:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21552):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
07-12 11:08:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21552):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-12 11:08:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
07-12 11:08:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-12 11:08:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-12 11:08:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21552):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-12 11:08:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21552):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 11:08:47.167: E/AndroidRuntime(21552):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
```

Native shared library placed "libs\armeabi\mylib.so" under my project folder.

Please help me what I did wrong?

Comment: Are you using cocos2dx?

Comment: No. I am not using cocos2dx.

Answer (score 0):

your library name should be

> libmylib.so

You should change the settings of the project which is generating the library and generate with correct name. then you can load this library using 
`System.loadLibrary("mylib");`
As a quick measure, you can just rename the library name and try.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) It Signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer. An ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable.

check somewhere you tried static initialization

Comment: Linked documentation 404s, here's a current, working link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html